# java scanner - how to split a mac address?

Tags: java

The mac address string may be in format:

00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee

or

00aabbccddee

I need a good way to retrieve the 6 parts.

Here my code:

```
public class Mac
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String mac = "00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee"; /* 00aabbccddee */
        Scanner s = new Scanner(mac);
        s.useDelimiter(":?"); /* zero or one occurrence */                                                                                                                             
        String t = null;
        while ((t = s.next("[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]")) != null)
            System.out.println(t);
    }
}
```

It throws a exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1394)
        at Mac.main(Mac.java:11)
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static String[] getMacAddressParts(String macAddress) {
    String[] parts = macAddress.split(":");
    if (parts.length == 0) {
        parts = new String[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            parts[i] = macAddress.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 1);
        }
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] splitMac(String mac) {
    String[] parts = null;
    if (mac.length() == 6*3) {
      parts = mac.split(":");
    } else if (mac.length() == 6*2) {
      parts = new String[6];
      parts[0] = mac.substring(0,1);
      parts[1] = mac.substring(2,3);
      parts[2] = mac.substring(4,5);
      parts[3] = mac.substring(6,7);
      parts[4] = mac.substring(8,9);
      parts[5] = mac.substring(10,11);
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("Invalid arg for mac addr: " + mac);
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting a delimiter for zero or more occurrences will split the string as every single char in the next() findings like this:

a
a
b
b
c
c
d
d
e
e

because you are saying if it does or doesn't find it, split it.

So looking for the next token that matches your regex "[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]" throws that exception because its trying to match one character with a 2 character regex every time, and it throws it then the token you are trying to get doesnt match the regex you are giving, thus doing the hasNext("Pattern") before prevents that.

Also you're code will throw a NoSuchElementException when the string stops reading the characters through the next() method, verify if it does have a next token with the hasNext("Pattern") in the while conditional.

So just remove the ? on the delimiter and it will work.

Example:

```
    String mac = "00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee"; /* 00aabbccddee */
    Scanner s = new Scanner(mac);
    s.useDelimiter(":"); /* zero or one occurrence */                                                                                                                             
    String t = null;
    while (s.hasNext("[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]"))
    {
        t = s.next("[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
  String mac = "00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee";

  String[] partsArray = mac.split(":");

  for(int i = 0; partsArray.length < i ;i++){
     String part = partsArray[i];
     System.out.println ("Splitted mac address part "+i+" is - "+part);
  }
```